# Counting the duplicate values in array and concatenating them?

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => test1
            [checkdata] => This is example1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => test1
            [checkdata] => This is example2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => test1
            [checkdata] => This is example3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => test2
            [checkdata] => This is example4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [title] => test3
            [checkdata] => This is example5
        )
```

)

This is my array. I want to make it like this:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [title] => test1
        [checkdata] => array(
           [0]=>This is example1
           [1]=>This is example2
           [3]=>This is example3
        )
     )


   [1] => Array
    (
        [title] => test2
        [checkdata] => array(
           [0]=>This is example4
           [1]=>This is example5

        )
     )    

)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far. What duplicate values are you talking about?

Comment: $j=0;
  
  foreach($myarray as $k=> $v){
   if(in_array($v['title'], $myarray)){
    
      $myarray[$j]['checkdata'] = $v['checkdata'];
      $j++;
      
     }
    
   }

Comment: What duplicates are you talking about? Can you explain your problem a bit more?

Comment: ok, like in the above example, test1 exist in array more than once, now i want the correspoinding checkdata values like This is example1 and This is example2 comes together

Answer (score 0):

A simple method using a nested loop:

[Codepad demo](http://codepad.org/7Is2Ip09)

```
$result = array();

foreach($arr as $val){
    $found = false;
    foreach($result as $key => $r){
        if($r['title'] == $val['title']){
            $result[$key]['checkdata'][] = $val['checkdata'];
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$found){
        $result[] = array(
            'title' => $val['title'],
            'checkdata' => array($val['checkdata'])
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it solved my problem :) Loves stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join two (sub) arrays by common key value, you can use array_merge_recursive

http://php.net/array_merge_recursive

```
$arr1['checkdata'] = 'This is example4';

$arr2['checkdata'] = 'This is example5';

$merged = array_merge_recursive ($arr1, $arr2);
```

Returns:

Array ( [checkdata] => Array ( [0] => This is example4 [1] => This is example5 ) )

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php
$foo = array(
  array(
    'title' => 'test1',
    'checkdata' => 'This is example1'
  ), array(
    'title' => 'test1',
    'checkdata' => 'This is example2'
  ),
  array(
    'title' => 'test1',
    'checkdata' => 'This is example3'
  ),
  array(
    'title' => 'test2',
    'checkdata' => 'This is example4'
  ),
  array(
    'title' => 'test3',
    'checkdata' => 'This is example5'
  ),
);

$out = [];

foreach ($foo as $value) {
    if (!isset($out[$value['title']])) {
        $out[$value['title']] = [
            'title' => $value['title'],
            'checkdata' => []
        ];
    }
    $out[$value['title']]['checkdata'][] = $value['checkdata'];
}

var_dump($out);
```